# Close two windows with one click in tkinter

Tags: python, windows, function, tkinter

I am trying to get a button in one function to close the window generated from another function. Here is a shortened version of the code. Basically I want the top window generated from `add_drink` to be closed when the `close_button` is clicked at the `save_drink` stage. How can I do this?

```
def save_drink(added_drink):
    drinks_list = []
    newtop = Toplevel(root)
    newtop.geometry("200x200")
    newtop.title("Drink Added")
    label = Label(newtop, text= "{} Added".format((added_drink.get())), font=('Mistral 10')).pack()
    close_button = Button(newtop, text="Close", command=newtop.destroy)
    close_button.pack()
    drinks_list.append(added_drink.get())


def add_drink():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    top.geometry("750x250")
    top.title("Record Drink")
    label = Label(top, text= "What drink did you have?", font=('Mistral 18')).pack()
    added_drink = Entry(top, font=6)
    added_drink.pack()
    added_drink_button = Button(top, text='Add Drink', font=3,
                                command=lambda: save_drink(added_drink)).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing `top` from `add_drink` as a parameter to `save_drink`

```
added_drink_button = Button(
    top,
    text='Add Drink',
    font=3,
    command=lambda top=top: save_drink(added_drink, top)  # add top to the lambda
).pack()
```

then modify `save_drink` to accept the `top` parameter and dispose of it accordingly
in a new function that handles closing both `Toplevel` widgets

```
def save_drink(added_drink, top):  # add 'top' here
    drinks_list = []
    newtop = Toplevel(root)
    newtop.geometry("200x200")
    newtop.title("Drink Added")
    label = Label(
        newtop,
        # I suspect there's some extra parentheses around 'format'
        text= "{} Added".format((added_drink.get())), font=('Mistral 10')
    ).pack()
    close_button = Button(
        newtop,
        text="Close",
        # call the 'close' function using a lambda to pass args
        command=lambda t=top, n=newtop: close(t, n)
    )
    close_button.pack()
    drinks_list.append(added_drink.get())
```

This function will close both windows when called by `close_button`

```
def close(top, newtop):  # pass both windows as parameters
    top.destroy()
    newtop.destroy()
```

This should work, though I suspect it might be easier to wrap both the `add_drink` and `save_drink` functions in a simple class so they can share information more easily.

Comment: I tried the code but am getting the following error: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: close() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'top' and 'newtop''

Comment: That's my mistake! I've updated my answer, but the gist is you need to change `command=close` to `command=lambda t=top, n=newtop: close(t, n)`. The problem is I wasn't passing the `top` and `newtop` params to the `close` function!